# Get x-axis of a transform in three.js

Tags: three.js

Is there a direct way to get the x-axis of a three.js transform? Or do I have to work it out from the `rotation` of the transform? If so, what is a good algorithm for doing this?

Comment: Do you mean a matrix transformation? Could you elaborate on the question a bit?

Comment: I have a node, and I want to align its x-axis with the normal to a given vertex. I believe that what I call a transform is THREE.Matrix4.